# Woocommerce override grouped product title

Tags: woocommerce

I've seen this on other themes but can't work out how it has been done. In my grouped product list, the title lists as Parent product title --> Child product title. I need it only to list the Child product title.

I can see the code to alter is:

```
<a href="' . get_permalink( $child_product['product']->id ) . '">' . $child_product['product']->post->post_title . '</a>
```

Either the post_title needs to overridden, or the code altered to...what?

Answer (score 3):

(Although this is old, it's still a common question with a prominent google ranking)

Woocommerce defines a filter, `woocommerce_product_title`, which allows you to pass a product's title through a function that modifies the way it will display.

Add a filter, probably in your theme's `functions.php`

`add_filter('woocommerce_product_title', 'clean_up_title');`

This is the function I'm currently using to accomplish this, no promises that it's the best way possible:

```
function clean_up_title($title){
    // check to see if there is an html arrow in the title
    if (strpos($title, '&rarr;')){
        $separator = '&rarr;';
    }

    // otherwise assume it's the character 
    else {
        $separator = '→';
    }

    // split the title into multiple parts at the arrows
    $prog_array = explode($separator, $title);

    // get the last part, the actual product name
    $prog_name = end($prog_array);

    // slice off any leading or trailing whitespace
    return trim($prog_name);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This would be a bit cleaner to do. Just 'return' the product title rather than 'edit' it.

```
function clean_product_title($title, $product) {

   return $product->post->post_title;;

}

add_filter('woocommerce_product_title', 'clean_product_title', 10, 2);
```

Comment: Very helpful to be able to pass the `$product` parameter.